# Class::isEnum need check this.getSuperclass() == java.lang.Enum.class;

Tags: java

```
public boolean isEnum() {
    // An enum must both directly extend java.lang.Enum and have
    // the ENUM bit set; classes for specialized enum constants
    // don't do the former.
    return (this.getModifiers() & ENUM) != 0 &&
        this.getSuperclass() == java.lang.Enum.class;
}
```

Why is the following check needed?

```
 this.getSuperclass() == java.lang.Enum.class
```

Is this following check not enough?

```
(this.getModifiers() & ENUM) != 0
```

Comment: what is: this.getModifiers() & ENUM supposed to do? I would rather argue it's the other way around

Comment: Because 'classes for specialized enum constants don't do the former'.

Comment: @user207421 classes for specialized enum constants don't do the *latter*; they do do the former. https://ideone.com/9TtQId

Answer (score 1):

Consider this code:

```
enum Foo { A{}, B }

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    System.out.println(Foo.A.getClass().isEnum());
    System.out.println(Foo.B.getClass().isEnum());
}
```

[This prints](https://ideone.com/i4prPf):

```
false
true
```

The class of `Foo.A` is not considered to be an enum; the class of `Foo.B` is.

This is because `Foo.A` is actually an instance of a subclass of `Foo`, not the enum class itself.

It's not clear why the check on the modifier bit is necessary; I would say it might be cheaper than the subsequent check, and thus avoid work in the common case, but it's just reference equality, which isn't expensive. Perhaps it's to guard against other JVM languages not enforcing the restriction of not being able to extend `Enum` directly.

Comment: Weird that `isEnum` is false for `A`! I have to remember this if I ever want to test whether a `Class` belongs to an enum. The easiest way to do that is probably with `Enum.class.isAssignableFrom(c)`.